# Multiple years in a listYear

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a calendar on a customer page in a custom application.

I would like to display all events (for a specific customer) for all time in listYear view.

I have a custom view as ListYearAll, and have set the date range from 1980 to 2230, which effectively would get all possible events, but it is still only displaying one year. In the documentation, it says you can specify a custom visible range.

```
 views: {
          listYearAll: {
            type: 'listYear',
            buttonText: 'List',
            visibleRange: {
              start: '1980-01-01',
              end: '2230-01-01'
            }
          }
        },
```

https://codepen.io/bestrong89/pen/bGdQZOz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By including the word "Year" in the view name, you're telling it to always set the visible range of the list to a year. This overrides any other `visibleRange` setting you have added. (And it would be the same idea if you specific `listMonth` or `listDay` for example). If you want to use a custom visible range, you must just tell it to use the `list` view, without specifying a pre-set time period.

So you can just change

```
type: "listYear"
```

to

```
type: "list"
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/QWbzNqM

Comment: Much appreciated! That took care of it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find this option on the docs.

Comment: @EduardoG I agree it's not hugely clear. It's sort of implied in the example  here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings